# Node.js multiparty upload is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

The `multiparty.Form()` is not working. I'm trying to print. (e.g. 2,3,4)

Here is my image upload code:

```
app.post('/gallery/add',function(req, res,next) {
var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var format = require('util').format;
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require('path');
var tempPath =req.files.image.path;
var filename2 =req.files.image.originalFilename;
req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    console.log('1');
   var form = new multiparty.Form();
   var image;
   var title;
form.on('error', next);
  form.on('close', function(err, fields, files){
      console.log('2');
      if(err) {
       next(err);
       console.log(err);
    } else {
  console.log('3');
      ins = fs.createReadStream(tempPath);
      ous = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/uploads/' + image.filename);
      util.pump(ins, ous, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          next(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect('/#gallery/add');
          res.end();
        }
      });
      //console.log('\nUploaded %s to %s', files.photo.filename, files.photo.path);
      //res.send('Uploaded ' + files.photo.filename + ' to ' + files.photo.path);
    }
    res.send(format('\nuploaded %s (%d Kb) as %s'
      , image.filename
      , image.size / 1024 | 0
      , title));
  });
 // listen on field event for title
  form.on('field', function(name, val){

  console.log('4');
    if (name !== 'title') return;
    title = val;
  });

  // listen on part event for image file
  form.on('part', function(part){
 console.log('5');
    if (!part.filename) return;
    if (part.name !== 'image') return part.resume();
    image = {};
    image.filename = part.filename;
    image.size = 0;
    part.on('data', function(buf){
      image.size += buf.length;
    });
  });

  // parse the form
   form.parse(req);

    });
});
```

It seems like the `form.on` method is not working.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you tell me, at what point your code reach

Comment: Yes, only '1' is printing in this

Comment: use this just after console.
var form = new multiparty.Form();
 
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
 
    return;

Comment: is it works or not??

Comment: No, it says fields and files are undefined.

Comment: Please format your code with proper and consistent indentation so we can read it as posted.

Answer (score 1):

just use it:

```
// parse a file upload 
    var form = new multiparty.Form();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty

Comment: @diksha, try this hope it'll provide some error, so you can debug more 
form.on('error', function(err){
console.log(err);
});

Comment: I can access the files, but there is only name and path with no data appearing: files: %@ { fieldName: 'image',
  originalFilename: 'photo1.png',
  path: '/var/folders/x4/01z7j18d7vz8rxrgcxt2w9dm0000gn/T/OMTuSjvM_Oj9OeUr44z0Mzk4.png',
  headers: 
   { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="image"; filename="photo1.png"',
     'content-type': 'image/png' },
  size: 152501 }  Do you know how I can access the image data submitted not just the path in order to store them in the database?